# Error: Failed account unlock attempt, is this an attack?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

[image]If I use my

```
geth --identity "MyNodeName" --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" 
--datadir Users/xxxx/TestChain1 --port "30303" --rpcaddr 
"127.0.0.1"  --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" -- 
networkid 123 init /Users/xxxx/CustomGenesis.json


 geth --identity "MyNodeName" --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain 
 "*" --datadir Users/xxxx/TestChain1 --port "30303" --nodiscover -- 
 rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --networkid 123 console
```

Everything works fine. But if I change rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" to a static address like 129.215.199.18 and run the above code, i will get the following warning in geth:

```
Failed account unlock attempt            
address=0x621C385fe616fBe096322E71d6f02631d520C1Ca 
err="could not decrypt key with given passphrase"
```

Note that this is the only account I had. Even if I try to unlock my account once I keep getting the above warning. It also prevents me to deploy the contract to the blockchain if I use remix and metamask. But I will not have any issue if I use rpcaddr "127.0.0.1"  in the above command line.

Also, when I send only one transaction via geth, the console keeps saying that a transaction has been submitted.

[image]

**Question**: What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is a brute-force attack against your password. Besides potentially stealing all of your ETH, descryption is relatively expensive computationally and could be a DOS vector.

You should never expose the `personal` API to the open internet. Consider disallowing external connections by setting your `rpcaddr` and `rpccorsdomain` to `localhost`. Even better, use IPC instead of RPC if your connection is local.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm developing a smart contract and user interface for that.   Ultimately I want external users to connect to it and use it. I need to tell to the users my static IP, so they can connect via a wallet like metamask. Therefore, my question is: how can I set my blockchain security and prevent those attacks?

Comment: You can ask another question if you want more specifics, but the gist is that you should only set `--rpcapi "eth,web3"` You should definitely not expose `personal`

Answer (score 2):

Sure, this is brute-force attack trying to unlock an account and send out a transaction. Never never never open up rpc port in public.